# Android Studio does not import all parts of an SVG Vector

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, svg, android-vectordrawable

I want to import some vector graphics from illustrator for the design of my android studio app. If I export my vector graphics as SVG, this works wonderfully. All parts of my project are successfully exported and the result is satisfactory (image 1). However, when I create this SVG file as a new Vector Asset in Android Studio, one of my  blue circles is suddenly missing (see image 2). What can be the reasons why Android studio does not import all parts of my SVG? Or could the reason be a wrong export from illustrator?

Edit: Added Picture 3 to show what happens if I use a online converter instead. The output is even worse.

Any Help is appreciated!

**Picture 1:**

[image: Picture 1 Exported SVG opend in Microsoft Edge, works as it should]

**Picture 2:**

[image: Picture 2 Previes in Android Studio (one circle is missing)]

**Image 3...Result when I use a online converter to get a xml vector(also wrong)***

[image: Result when I use a online converter to get a xml vector]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of the SVG that is displayed in the converter window is rendered by a built-in SVG renderer in Android Studio.  *It's a preview of the SVG*. It does not necessarily reflect what the output of the converter will be.

So the bug you are seeing is with the built-in SVG renderer.

VectorDrawables don't really support gradient fills.  At least the converter doesn't support them.  So even if the displayed SVG were perfect, the generated VectorDrawable won't include the gradient circles anyway.

So you have a few alternative approaches:

1. Change your circles to solid fill and then convert to VectorDrawables.
2. Like #1, but add gradients by using predefined gradient definitions.
3. Use an actual SVG rendering library (like AndroidSVG) in your app.
4. Switch to using a bitmap background (ie PNG)
5. Draw the background yourself using `Canvas` methods.

Personally, I would go with #3.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio doesn't convert complex graphics into vector drawable. It only converts flat icons. You have to use a png here dude !!

Comment: Thanks for your answer and welcom to stackoverflow! Thats also something I have alread tought about...the thing is thant I dont unterstand why it works with the one circle and not with the other due to their relative symmetrical appearance. Please let me know if you have any more thoughts on this. Thanks